# Inner regular Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space (l.c.H. space) then the Riesz representation theorem says that positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ are given by Borel measures on $X$. Unfortunately there is not a one-to-one correspondence, and so one introduces some class of "regular" measures on $X$ and show that for these measures there is a one-to-one correspondence. These measures are then usually called Radon. However, there is not a unique way to do this, and so Radon measure means different things for different authors. Now to my knowledge the two most used definitions of Radon are:

1. Finite on compact sets, inner regular on open sets, and outer regular on Borel sets.
2. Finite on compact sets, and inner regular on Borel sets.

Finally, for a l.c.H. group $G$ one defines Haar measure as an invariant Radon measure, and one can show that this is unique up to a constant, and if we want left or right invariance. Now, my question is the following. For Haar measure I have only seen definition 1. of Radon being used. So is it possible to also use 2.? And does this make things harder/easier or just the same?

Comment: This kind of (artificial) problem is due to working with pathological spaces which locally compact can very well be. Also, a more useful notion is locally finite (each point has an open neighborhood of finite measure) rather than finite on compact sets. On a Polish space, any locally finite Borel measure is inner and outer regular on all Borel sets. Namely, in that setting, you can can forget about the notion(s) of Radon measure.